# C# help couldn't find the path (LOG IN SYSTEM)

Tags: c#, path

So my program is working well but whenever i sign up on Form 2  it says that it couldn't find the path i don't know what's wrong please help i need to pass it later , i don't know if i need to make a new folder on the C: just to get the LOGIN.ID

{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string username, password;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID");
            username = sr.ReadLine();
            password = sr.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();

            if (username == textBox1.Text && password == textBox2.Text)
                  MessageBox.Show("Log-in Successfull", "Success!");
            else
                 MessageBox.Show("Username or password is wrong! ","Error!");

        }
        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The user doesn't exist!", "Error!");

        }
    }
}
```

}

//form 2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Hide();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter ("C\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID"); 
            sw.Write(textBox1.Text + "\n" + textBox2.Text);
            sw.Close();

        }
        catch(System.IO.DriveNotFoundException )

        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\" + textBox1.Text);
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID");
            sw.Write(textBox1.Text + "\n" + textBox2.Text);
            sw.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: You keep mixing "C\\" and "C:\\". What's "C\\"? It's nonsense. Fix your paths so they're consistently "C:\\".

Comment: how could i fix it ? should i make a folder for C :\\
Example C\test\

Comment: example : @form 1
 var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C\test1\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID");
                username = sr.ReadLine();
                password = sr.ReadLine();
                sr.Close();

Comment: Stop using "C\". It doesn't mean anything. Never use it again. Ever. Never ever ever. It's supposed to be "C:\". You need to read up on Windows file paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `:` after the `C` drive in many places in your code

```
var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID");
```

change to

```
var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\" + textBox1.Text + "\\login.ID");
```

Comment: thankyou thankyou now it's okay i just created a new folder in C : to correct the path .. im sorry i haven't sleep yet i do 4 programs because i need to pass it later.. thankyou :) !

Answer (score 0):

You should take a close look at your paths. i don't think c\ exists.
Probably you are using C:\
If you still have problems maybe your TextBox1.Text returns a wrong path.